# Why can't I access session variable in multiple files in PHP?

Tags: php, session

I have a login checker that redirects the user to a homepage if the check succeeds. I save the username in session variable at 'username' index.

```
<?php

ob_start();
include("db.php");
session_start();
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];


$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=pg_query($sql);

$count=pg_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
header("location:homepage.php");
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I try to access the index but get an error that it doesn't exists

```
 <p>WELCOME!</p>
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

I call session_start in each file so I can't see the problem.

Comment: Note:
To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.  -- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php  That means you have to put the `session_start()` at the top, before the welcome.

Comment: I think **session_start();** should be at the beginning of the **PHP** page.

Comment: Why are you using ob_start and ob_end_flush ?

Comment: nope, that doesn't solve it. I got the session_start to the top and still can't access session variable.

Comment: You must call `session_start()` in every file (on top) in which you want to use Sessions.

Comment: I've called session start in each file, you can see it in the code.

Comment: What error exactly do you have?

Answer (score 0):

```
   Check  your $count variable's  value, 
   I think your  session is not creating due to your conditions.

   If your $count value will 1 then it will print session's value.

   Your code is fine, no need to change the code, only check your conditions.

   I am sure your issue will be solve.  

   Change
   if($count==1){
          $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
          header("location:homepage.php");
      } 
   To 

    if($count){
          $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
          header("location:homepage.php");
      }
```

Comment: That makes 0 sense since I know which condition is true because if it is false it echoes "Wrong Password"!

Comment: have you checked $myusername value?

Comment: yes, of course. even if it's blank there would be an index 'username'

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
session_start();
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

if($myusername!="" and $mypassword!="")
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result=pg_query($sql);

    $count=pg_num_rows($result);

    if($count==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
        header("location:homepage.php");
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
}else {
    echo "Please Enter Username and Password";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

what if some one enters `' or 1 or '` as password? do sanitize inputs.

As for the missing `$_SESSION['username']`

first check the value of $count to verify that the credentials are correct.

if that is fine check your browser. php sessions are based on a cookie value. check your if cookies are allowed in our browser.

if allowed look for a cookie named PHPSESSID, if its set and valid.

This way you should be able to pin point your problem.

[this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-this-cookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) can help in inspecting cookie values in chrome.